# Sending Ag-Grid Row Data Array to Back-End in Nodejs & Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, ag-grid

I know I'm close on this but I can't figure out how to pass the data array to the controller. This function works perfectly to build an array based on user input. ---Note that the client side includes a post method - the endpoint works in Postman.

```
 //Intent is to trigger the function and capture the array - then ultimately refine the code if it worked.
<form id=liquid action="/api/entities/liquid" method="post" >
 <button onclick="getLiquidity()" class="button">Console Data</button>
 <button type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">Save Liquidity</button>
 <div id="tblCash" style="height: 250px; width:100%;" class="ag-theme-alpine"> </div>
 </form>


function getLiquidity() {
  
      const rowData = [];
      gridOptions.api.forEachNode(function (node) {
        rowData.push(node.data);
      });
   
        
}

//This doesn't work 
module.exports = rowData
//ReferenceError: rowData is not defined
```

Console.log shows the following:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "",
        "columnA": "data",
        "columnB": "data",
        "columnC": "data",
        "columnD": "data",
        "columnE": "data",
        "columnF": "data"
    },
  ]
```

I can't figure out how to send rowData to the controller where Sequelize takes over.

```
//controller.js
//imports GridOptions file for Ag-Grid and where rowData is built
const rowData= require("../../public/scripts/liquid")

const liquid = {
      ID:"2240", //Using this for testing
      columnA:rowData[0].inputA,
      columnB:rowData[0].inputB,
      columnC:rowData[0].inputC,
      columnD:rowData[0].inputD,
      columnE:rowData[0].inputE,
      columnF: rowData[0].inputF,
      updatedAt: rowData[0].updatedAt,
      createdAt: rowData[0].createdAt
  };
```

rowData remains empty

I expected to be able to export rowData as an array but it doesn't work. As shown below, the response shows an empty array.

```
{
trxID: 3211,
ID: 2240,
columnA: null,
columnB: null,
columnC: null,
columnD: null,
columnE: null,
columnF: null,
updatedAt: "2023-02-01T18:57:29.480Z",
createdAt: "2023-02-01T18:57:29.480Z"
}
```

Comment: Firstly, `require(...)` and `module.exports` are node.js specific, and you can't use those in the frontend. Secondly, you are declaring `rowData` inside a function, how do you expect it to be available outside of it?

Comment: @ISAE -Thanks for taking a look. I get what you are saying and I'm trying to understand what I'm missing. I edited my original post to include the form part on the client side.  I was thinking I could call the function within the form. I was expecting req.body and got null values.  I'm okay with capturing textbox values but I'm not sure how to do this with ag-grid - that's why the function is there.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the specific js issues that others have commented on, I think that you are missing a fundamental concept here.

That is, the grid is intended to be a view component that represents your data.

It should not be the repository for your data.

You should keep your data as an array of objects whose properties represent a "row" of data. You then bind that array to the grid's "rows" property.

If you want to do something with your data, like send it to your back-end, you would use your data array to do so, and should not have to reference the grid to "get" the data.

So, for instance, your code:

```
gridOptions.api.forEachNode(function (node) {
    rowData.push(node.data);
});
```

should be entirely unnecessary, as you should already have the data which you  bound to the grid.

Comment: I appreciate the guidance. To clarify, I'm trying to use the grid for data entry. I render the grid on the client side, set the cells to editable, and then send the updated row data. The function works to package the array but I'm lost as to  how to get that to the backend. Thoughts?? Does that change your response?

Comment: I don't think it changes anything. If you want to add a row, add an object to your bound data array, and let the grid reflect that, rather than poking data directly into the grid.